# Repeated uses of TOP in query

Tags: ms-access-2013

Finding TOP items in query

I have an Access query with fields (in simplified form) name, type, value. I need to extract the top x records (according to value) FOR EVERY PAIR (name, type) with x depending on the pair. The query already has the column "value" sorted for each pair.

Solution 1. Do separate queries per pair, take the top x in each and build the union of the queries. Wrong! the number of pairs is large, Access can't handle the resulting query.

Solution 2. Add an extra column to the query, call it "Valid" and set it to True in all records. Then use VBA to traverse the recordset items of the query one by one and set Valid to False for the non-top items. Then do an additional query dropping the false records. Wrong again, the recordset is not editable in VBA (even though "Valid" has nothing to do with any tables used in the query). Yes, I opened the recordset in VBA with dbOpenDynaset -- no dice.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Sample data accompanied by an expected result would help us to better understand what you are looking to achieve here.

Comment: If your statement that ms access could not handle the amount of unions you would need, it sounds like you need some vba code to run the TOP query over the many rows/tables you need and to insert them into a "temp table", one that is primarily/only used for this purpose.